# Android: API Level and Kernel Version

Tags: android, linux-kernel

Just started working on Embedded Android. And got confused within **How to figure out which Kernel Version uses which API Level? How to figure out this info? OR Where can I find a relation between which API Level is used in what Kernel version?**

I mean, lets say to try Android 5.1, API Level 22 is used, but in which Kernel Version provides support for that?

Please correct me if I'm missing something, I'm new to Embedded Android, though I have worked on Embedded Linux.

Thank you in advance...!!!

Comment: I believe the easiest will be to check directly on the source: https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html and the reason I said that it's because on all my years of Android development I've never see any official docs saying which version comes with each kernell

Comment: Hi, I am just curious why are you needing to know what kernel the system is running on ? I think the android API level is enough. I am an android developper and I have never developed for linux embed system .)

Comment: @KevDev, yes you're right at your POV, but I'm a embedded developer and I'm trying to port Embedded Android on some Board. So I need to know in how many ways(Which Kernel and which Android version are compatible) I can configure Android for any board?!!